# CTE query to find all deadlocks based on parent spid and blocked spid

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have captured the spid, blockedByspid columns in a Table SPIDtable
the values are some thing like this
here the deadlock cycle is 116->243->248->116
There are many such deadlocks in this table.

```
spid    blockedBy
116 208
116 243
243 248
248 116
```

I have written CTE query to print out all such cycles

This is finding some cycles, but it is halting after maximum 100 recursion, is there a better approach

```
  ;WITH cte( spid, blockedBy, isCycle)
  as
  (
     select spid, blockedBy , 0 FROM SPIDTable
     where blockedby <>0  
     union all
     select S.spid , S.blockedBy, ( case when CTE.blockedBy = S.spid then 1 else 0 end) as cycle  from CTE
     inner join SPIDtable S
     on S.blockedBy = CTE.spid    
  )
  select * from CTE where isCycle =1
```

Comment: Look at trace flags 1204 and 1222 for logging comprehensive deadlock information as they are detected by SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, a deadlock graph will have at least once cycle. As such, if you just run your query on blocker.spid = blocked.blockedBy, you will iterate forever unless you have a termination clause. Here's what I came up with:

```
with SPIDTable as (
    select * from (values 
        (116, 208),
        (116, 243),
        (243, 248),
        (248, 116)
    ) as x(spid, blockedBy)
)
, cte as (
    select spid
        , blockedBy
        , 0 as isCycle, spid as [starter]
        , cast(spid as nvarchar(max)) as [chain]
        , 1 as [level]
    FROM SPIDTable
    where blockedby <> 0  

    union all

    select S.spid , S.blockedBy
    , case when CTE.starter = S.spid then 1 else 0 end as cycle
    , cte.starter as [starter]
    , cte.chain + '/' + cast(s.spid as nvarchar(max)) as [chain]
    , cte.[level] + 1 as [level]
    from CTE
    inner join SPIDtable S
        on S.blockedBy = CTE.spid
    where s.spid <> cte.starter
)
select * from CTE
order by [level]
```

Notice that in this example, all of the "level 3" rows represent the same cycle (namely 116 → 248 → 243 → 116). But in all cases, the rows with the highest level will be complete deadlock cycles (where the last (omitted) spid will just be the first spid in the chain).

Comment: this is looking promising and giving me desired results.